# Correcting integration error by supplying assumptions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I wrote some auxiliary functions to help evaluate my main function `ELC`, which always return the error

> Unable to prove that integration limits {0, t} are real. Adding assumptions may help

```
pie = 10000; tt = 1; ch = 500; cpr = 8000; cf = 12000; cs = 2000; 
B1= 4; B2 = 2; h1 = 4; h2 = 12;
f1[t_] := (B1/h1)*(t/h1)^(B1 - 1)*E^-(t/h1)^B1;
f2[t_] := (B2/h2)*(t/h2)^(B2 - 1)*E^-(t/h2)^B2;
R1[t_] := Integrate[(B1/h1)*(u/h1)^(B1 - 1)*E^-(u/h1)^B1, {u, t, ∞}];
R2[t_] := Integrate[(B2/h2)*(u/h2)^(B2 - 1)*E^-(u/h2)^B2, {u, t, ∞}];
w[t_] := h1*(t/h2)^(B2/B1) ;
Rs[t_] := R1[t] + Integrate[f1[u]*R1[t - u + w[u]], {u, 0, t}];
fs[t_] := f1[t] + Integrate[f1[u]*f1[t - u + w[u]], {u, 0, t}] - f1[t]*R1[w[t]];
ELC[tp_] := tp*Rs[tp - tt] + Integrate[(tt + t)*fs[t], {t, 0, tp - tt}];
```

I wonder if I have to assume that variables are real in every function I wrote or in only just the last one ELC and is there anyway to let Mathematica know that all variables are real everywhere.

Comment: This `Rs[tp - tt]` gives that warning all by itself

Comment: It is possible to specify assumptions for the whole notebook.  Look up `$Assumptions`.